# PYTHON Need to print error message for non-integers as well as integers

Tags: python

When I run the following code in python after entering an integer (eg. 4, 5, 6, 100, etc.), it prints the `"ERROR: the choice can only be 1, 2, or 3." message.`

However, if I enter a letter like 'xyz' I get the following:

```
builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

What I need is to get the error message to display whenever ANYTHING but a 1, 2, or 3 is entered and I can't figure out how to do that. Thanks.

```
print('What is your choice? Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors: ')
choice2 = int(input())
while choice2 != 1 and choice2 != 2 and choice2 != 3:
   print("ERROR: the choice can only be 1, 2, or 3.")
   choice2 = int(input("Please enter a correct choice: "))
```

Comment: Google "python try except" and read a few tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the `choice2` variable as a `str`, like so:

```
choice2 = input()
while choice2 != "1" and choice2 != "2" and choice2 != "3":
    print("Error ...")
    choice2 = input("Please ...")
```

Then, later, if you need it to be an `int`, you can convert it:

```
choice2 = int(choice2)
```

*Aside*: Rather than testing each value with `!=`, try `not in`, like so:

```
while choice2 not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    ...
```

Comment: THANK YOU. This was it, all I needed was to change int(input()) to just (input()) and put quotes around the 1 2 and 3 in the while statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit your code to something like this using a `try ... except` block:

```
choice2 = 0
while 1:
    try:
        choice2 = int(input('What is your choice? Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors: '))
        if choice2 == 1 or choice2 == 2 or choice2 == 3:
            break
        else:
            print("ERROR: the choice can only be 1, 2, or 3.")
    except Exception:
        print("ERROR: the choice must be an integer between 1 and 3.")

print("You entered: ", choice2)
```